# Publish a script online

Tags: python

I have a Python script written up and the output of this script is a list.

Right now I need to get it online and make it accessible to others. I looked at Django , but then I realized that it may be kind of hard to create the UI. Is there any simple way to create a UI in Django and map it to an existing Python script.

Right now I using nltk, numpy, sqlite3 and things like that. Or is there a simpler way by which I can proceed?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Django is redundant.

You can use something smaller, Flask or maybe Aiohttp.

For example, all you need in `aiohttp`:
basic hmtl template
handler for one url (here you will call your script)
aiohttp webserver

The main idea:
Your server catch some url (for example `/`),
start your script, receives result,
respond with your html template (also render script result in it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a flask App. 
Just do a *pip install Flask* and try the code below

```
from flask import Flask
import flask
import json
from flask import Response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test',methods=['GET'])
def test():
    ''' 
    GET: Receives the request in /test route and returns a response containing {"response": [1,2,3]}
    '''
    my_list = [1,2,3]
    resp = Response(response=json.dumps({"response": my_list}), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    return resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8082)
```

Then to test your app from your browser accessing
**localhost:8082/test**
or also through some app like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

I would suggest looking into something like [React](https://github.com/facebook/react) for creating the UI. This way your UI would only make calls to your Flask server.